# How can I rename the Firebase Project ID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I succeeded to rename my Firebase Project Name. I want to rename my **Project ID** as well, yet, it looks read-only.

I tried via `Settings -> General`, and via `Permissions -> IAM` etc, but with no success.

Does anyone know of any way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to change the ID?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to change the project ID of a project.

Comment: Note that Ettore's answer allows you to change the name (2x) of a project, but not the ID. I'm pretty sure the *project ID* of a project still cannot be changed. If you think it can be, please share precise steps on how to change it.

Comment: Feature request - I would love the ability to change the project id as well.

Comment: You can [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)

Comment: I filed a feature request for "Rename Project ID"

Comment: Got a quick response - "I filed this as a feature request and the engineers have a feedback about this. They have mentioned that, since project IDs must be globally unique identifiers in order to be used in features such as Realtime Database URLs, Firebase Hosting subdomain, and so on, it's unlikely that we would support editing the project ID due to the security and privacy issues that could result. - Christmer" So that's a no :)

Answer (score 6):

I had to Delete my project and Create a new one.

How to Delete : `Settings -> Permissions -> All Projects`

How to Create [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#3).

Do not forget running:

`firebase use --add` from your project dir, and test both:

`firebase serve` and

`firebase deploy`.

Answer (score 6):

You can just delete the current project, make a new project, download its google-services.json file and replace it with the current one in your app folder then finally you'll have to clean your project from Build -> CleanProject! That's it!

Comment: What about the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this doc

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en

> The project ID is a unique identifier for a project. When you first
>   create a project, you can accept the default generated project ID or
>   create your own. **A project ID cannot be changed after the project is
>   created,** so if you are creating a new project, be sure to choose an ID
>   that you'll be comfortable using for the lifetime of the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the ID of a project. You have to create a new one.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in several other answers.

Answer (score -2):

Can change **project ID** just when create project and can set any name not taken .

[image]