# How to change Firebase id by creating another project

Tags: android, firebase

I want to rename my Firebase id.

I found out that the only way to do that is to create new project

[How can I rename the Firebase Project ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941416/how-can-i-rename-the-firebase-project-id)

I've created a new project and pasted the same android applicationId.

I've added the correct json file into my project.

Then Firebase suggests me to run my app in order to test the connection. 
I've reinstalled my app, but I have no connection.
Does it mean that I should delete the prerious app in order to make this app work?

Comment: Have you added the correct JSON file to your project?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I did

Comment: try file -> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @ked does not work. It's still on Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: @AlexMamo any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **change the default project** will sove this problem.
Run this command:

```
firebase use --add <YOUR_NEW_PROJECT_NAME>
```

Or if you want to test a project in emulators which is not exist on your firebase, just **delete the default project** by running:

```
firebase use --clear
```